# Casperjs click method

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm pretty new to casperjs and javascript in general, but I have pretty extensive coding experience in other realms. Currently the code I'm trying to get running is just going to a website and clicking on a link, which should be straightforward, but I'm having trouble.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.start('http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&page=1&sort=Earnings');

casper.then(function() {
    this.test.assertExists({
        type: 'xpath',
        path: '//*[@class="paddingLeft5 txt11px txt666"]/a[text()="Next"]'
    }, "Got Here");
});

casper.then(function() {
    var firstUrl = this.getCurrentUrl()
});

casper.thenClick(x('//*[@class="paddingLeft5 txt11px txt666"]/a[text()="Next"]'), function() {
    console.log("Woop!");
});

casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return this.getCurrentUrl() != firstUrl;
    });
}, function then() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});


casper.run();
```

currently this times out after 5000ms without wrapping in the waitFor it simply prints the same url twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for.
Note that I moved `firstUrl` to be a global variable; this way, the `Casper.waitFor()` has access to it.

Also, using `this.evaluate()` inside of the `Casper.waitFor()` was unnecessary and actually inhibiting receiving the error message because neither `this` nor `firstUrl` existed on the remote page. This is because any variables that you want to have access to inside of an `Casper.evaluate()` must be passed as arguments after the function.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
var firstUrl;
casper.start('http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&page=1&sort=Earnings');

casper.then(function() {
    this.test.assertExists({
        type: 'xpath',
        path: '//*[@class="paddingLeft5 txt11px txt666"]/a[text()="Next"]'
    }, "Got Here");
});

casper.then(function() {
    firstUrl = this.getCurrentUrl()
});

casper.thenClick(x('//*[@class="paddingLeft5 txt11px txt666"]/a[text()="Next"]'), function() {
    console.log("Woop!");
});

casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.getCurrentUrl() != firstUrl;
}, function then() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});


casper.run();
```

This is the result that I get when running the code above:

```
Woop!
http://www.guru.com/emp/search.aspx?keyword=#&&sort=Earnings&page=2
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks so much for that. Didn't know about wrapping my function in evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a website heavily relying on JavaScript for its navigation…

You should probably try to [waitFor](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) the url to change before processing your next step.

Comment: tried your advice, and the request ended up timing out. I updated the question though if you have any more advice to give.